# I'm looking at my SQL code in Microsoft Access and I see nothing wrong. I try to run the query and it says "syntax error in create table statement."

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
CREATE TABLE Authors 
(
    Au_Num      INT (3) PRIMARY KEYA,
    Au_LName    VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    Au_FName    VARCHAR (10),
    Book_Number INT (2),
    Client_Name VARCHAR (20)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing the parenthesized numbers from INT declarations works:

```
CREATE table Authors (
Au_Num INT Primary Key,
Au_LName VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Au_FName VARCHAR(10),
Book_Number Int,
Client_Name VARCHAR(20)
);
```

If the primary key should be an autonumber:

```
CREATE table Authors (
Au_Num AUTOINCREMENT Primary Key,
Au_LName VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Au_FName VARCHAR(10),
Book_Number Int,
Client_Name VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Data types such as int, bigint, datetime, smallint, tinyint, bit, bool and date has predefined length, hence it is not required to specify the length explicitly.

> Remove the length for int data types

```
create table Authors (
Au_Num      INT  Primary Key,
Au_LName  VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
Au_FName  VARCHAR (10),
Book_Number Int,
Client_Name   VARCHAR (20)

);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know that INT doesn't need a character length definition. I'm new to SQL and this really helped.  Is that why my code didn't run?

Comment: Yeah, that is one of the reasons, also, there was a typo in the primary key.